# KnockoutJS: Using 'html' binding, new elements not binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model which contains a ko.observable representing the conent of a div, like so:

```
function claimContainerViewModel(elem, api) {
    this.content = ko.observable('<somecontent>');
}
```

At some later time, I update that content using an AJAX call, and I have a div with the following binding:

```
<div id="ClaimContainer" data-bind="html: content">
```

The HTML returned for 'content' has data-bind's of it's own, and this is the issue: None of those bindings are being parsed. According to Knockout, and every source I've read, this is supposed to happen. When using the 'html' binding, KO is supposed to be smart enough to do a re-bind.

Is this a bug in KO 2.2.0 (the version I am stuck with right this very second), or am I misinterpreting how the html binding handler works? And before anyone asks, no applyBindings will not work in this case, because the container uses an html bind, which applyBindings assumes is supposed to handle the re-bind itself (I've confirmed this by stepping down in to KO's code).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This is the final version of my custom binding. This now works automatically, doesn't doubly bind, and works just like the 'html' binding, but more dynamic.

```
if (!ko.bindingHandlers['dynhtml']) {
    ko.bindingHandlers['dynhtml'] = {
        'init': function() {
            return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
        },
        'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            ko.utils.setHtml(element, valueAccessor());
            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
        }
    };
}
```

***Please, please, PLEASE be aware*** that this can be unsafe if you don't know the source of your HTML. Very, very unsafe. If unsanitized user input can ever make it in to your HTML, this could be a huge security hole, so watch out for cross site scripting attacks.

Comment: One caveat: This doesn't AUTOMATICALLY do the rebind, you still need to call applyBindings. This just allows that. From my understanding 'template' bindings work much better in this case, but they aren't an option for my use case...so this works for me.

Comment: Updated one last time with my final version which is automatic, doesn't doubly bind, and just works better. Note I set controlsDescendantBindings back to true so the KO engine doesn't double bind, and when the value of the dynhtml binding changes, we forcibly rebind descendants.

Comment: Matt, this totally rocked. It saved me an enormous amount of work!

Comment: Matt, Could you please add the html required to make it work? I would like to be able to import many html fragments and KO them.  If the html fragments are all written by me, then it's safe ?

Comment: I confirm this works on v3.4.2. As for how to use just place the above code somewhere in your JS. Then just do a simple data-bind="dynhtml: myhtml" in the div you wanna populate. It will work just as the html binding but wll re-bind everything once it changes.