# knockout js foreach binding is not updating when used in custom element (components.register)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
  ko.components.register("toast-container", {
    viewModel: ToastViewModel,
    template: '<div data-bind="foreach: array1"><div data-bind="text:someText"> </div></div>'
});

function ToastViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.array1 = ko.observableArray();
    self.Onclick = function () {
        self.array1.push({ someText: "some content" });
    }
}
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ToastViewModel());
});
```

When i push some content in array1 dynamically, the UI is not updating.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```js
ko.components.register("toast-container", {
    viewModel: ToastViewModel,
    template: '<div class="array" data-bind="foreach: array1"><div data-bind="text:someText"> </div>  </div>    <button data-bind="click: Onclick">Click me</button>      '
});

function ToastViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.array1 = ko.observableArray();
    self.Onclick = function () {
        //alert("click!");
        self.array1.push({ someText: "some content" });
    }
}
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings({}, $("#host")[0]);
});
```

```css
#host {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.array {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="host">
    <div data-bind="component: { name: 'toast-container'}"></div>
</div>
```

Note: the model is created inside component, thus you need not to create a new one in the applyBindings function call.

**Update 1:** Button is outside the component, component model has been splitted.

```js
ko.components.register("toast-container", {
    viewModel: ToastContainerViewModel,
    template: '<div class="array" data-bind="foreach: array"><div data-bind="text:someText"> </div>  </div>          '
});

function ToastContainerViewModel(params) {
    self.array = params.array;
}
function ToastViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.array1 = ko.observableArray();
    self.Onclick = function () {
        //alert("click!");
        self.array1.push({ someText: "some content" });
    }
}
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ToastViewModel(), $("#host")[0]);
});
```

```css
#host {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.array {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="host">
    <button data-bind="click: Onclick">Click me</button>
    <toast-container params="array: array1"></toast-container>
</div>
```

Comment: if <button data-bind="click: Onclick">Click me</button> markup is outside component template, then UI is not updated.

Comment: of course. in this case ToastViewModel will contain your array only. The array should be passed as a component parameter. And another outer model will contain as array + click handler.

Comment: I tried passing obeservableArray as parameter to component from external viewmodel, still it is not working when you add or remove from that observableArray. i.e the UI is not updating when changes in that array...

Comment: @shailendrakumar - i've updated first code snippet, the button is outside the component now, models are separated, check the "Update 1"

Comment: @TSV: Will it work if the html is loaded from external file? I mean if the component: template is loaded like...  template: { require: 'text!myfile.html' }

Comment: @JenniferMichelle I think - yes, IMHO it shouldn't depend on the way the template has been loaded. But speaking honestly I haven't tested it.

Comment: @TSV: External html doesn't seem to work, and may have to do with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756686/knockoutjs-using-html-binding-new-elements-not-binding/ .  I'm still having trouble with it.

Comment: @TSV: I posted a new question here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390862/knockout-binding-external-template-files
This is specifically about binding the templates external html files.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle: I'll try to check it out today.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle: I've published a sample - how to load component via requirejs - at GitHub: https://github.com/tsv2013/ko-requirejs-sample . Usage: "npm install", "grunt", then open in browser "http://localhost:8080/index.html"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the onclick is never getting called. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonr22/w36yuLvr/.

All I've done is bind your onclick event so that it actually gets called, and I added a default item to the array so that it can be clicked, like this:

```
ko.components.register("toast-container", {
    viewModel: ToastViewModel,
     template: '<div data-bind="click: Onclick, foreach: array1"><div data-bind="text:someText"></div></div>'
});

function ToastViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.array1 = ko.observableArray([{someText: 'foo'}]);
    self.Onclick = function () {
        self.array1.push({ someText: "some content" });
    }
}
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ToastViewModel());
});
```