# KnockoutJS bug changing content of html binding (outside knockout) breaks html binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Related, but does not solve the problem: [KnockoutJS: Using 'html' binding, new elements not binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756686/knockoutjs-using-html-binding-new-elements-not-binding)

If you have a `html` binding on an element, and change the inner html of this `html` binding outside knockout and/or the knockout viewmodel, you no longer have control of altering the original `html` binding. Please see the below snippet

I'm more interested in **keeping** the method by which the content is altered (running raw javascript/jquery) and would rather understand / fix why calling `setdefault()` does not update the binding

Any docs or links would also be helpful

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var VIEWMODEL = function(){
   var _ = this;
    
    _.content = ko.observable("<div>content</div>")
    _.asyncoperation = function(){
     $("#target")[0].innerHTML = "<div>async operation content</div>";
    }
    _.setdefault = function(){
     _.content("<div>content</div>");
    }
  };
  var vm = new VIEWMODEL();
  
  ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#container")[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="target" data-bind="html: content"></div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  
  <button data-bind="click: asyncoperation">async operation to replace text</button>
  <button data-bind="click: setdefault">set to default</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I can't find any docs/links that explain why this is the case exactly, but this is generally an inadvisable approach to using knockout.  Why exactly do you want to update the contents without using knockout?

Comment: I'm limited to changing this content because of an AB test. The two systems are separate and I need to change html based upon either A or B. I would rather not make my viewmodel on the window to change this `ko.observable` that way

Answer (score 2):

In Knockout, observables don't normally react to updates that don't actually change the value. But this can be altered using the [`notify` extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#forcing-observables-to-always-notify-subscribers), which the below example shows.

On the other hand, it's usually better to go through Knockout if possible. You could use something like [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) to do this.

### Using Postbox

```
_.content = ko.observable("<div>content</div>").subscribeTo("content");
_.asyncoperation = function() {
    ko.postbox.publish("content", "<div>async operation content</div>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLdv296r/

### Using notify extender

```
_.content = ko.observable("<div>content</div>").extend({notify:'always'});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var VIEWMODEL = function(){
   var _ = this;
    
    _.content = ko.observable("<div>content</div>").extend({notify:'always'});
    _.asyncoperation = function(){
     $("#target")[0].innerHTML = "<div>async operation content</div>";
    }
    _.setdefault = function(){
     _.content("<div>content</div>");
    }
  };
  var vm = new VIEWMODEL();
  
  ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#container")[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="target" data-bind="html: content"></div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  
  <button data-bind="click: asyncoperation">async operation to replace text</button>
  <button data-bind="click: setdefault">set to default</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

would something like this work? update the model on an onclick event outside of the model definition. you are still updating the observable but outside of the model definition.

here is a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32527/

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
          ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
          $('#asyncoperation').click(function() {
              mymodel.content("<div>async operation content</div>");
              });

          });
```

Comment: Ideally, no. I would prefer to avoid having my separate system have access directly to the viewmodel, but I'll consider it if I can't find other options

Comment: I think this is the answer.  Create an intermediate setter function if you don't want the 2nd system to directly access the viewmodel.